# For what reason installing GitLab through Docker is a good idea?

Tags: docker

To install GitLab on my company, I have two main choices:

- Use Docker
- Use a regular package

This kind of installation doesn't really need to be portable and would probably require a whole VM dedicated to it. So why is the Docker alternative a good solution ?

Answer (score 2):

I like putting applications into containers, because:

- installation is easier
- you can easily split configuration, core application and database

  - easier to switch to a different database
- if you have messed it up, just delete the core container, link your database and your configuration to it and you will be fine again
- gitlab runs in its own separated environment

  - this also gives you security advantages

Often programs are very complicated to be installed (I haven't installed GitLab by myself yet, just used the containers) which is why I often tend to use containers, because I do not want to think about the installation process -- just a docker-compose or docker-command and it's running. That sufficiently convinces me to use it.